# Request gets response very slow, only first time it is fired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Our application use MongoDB, ruby1.9 and rails3.2.

The problem happens when we try to get user profile(/users/first_name-last_name). Not on all user profiles, but only on user profiles those have a lot of embedded collection data. (notifications ~ 10 000, following items ~ 600) Rendering is done with rabl.

In development mode there is interesting part of this problem:

When we send request for getting data of 'problematic user', there is no response for more than 60 seconds (and we get bad response gateway error), but if you open profile of that same user in other tab after 5 seconds of time when first request is sent you get response in less then 7 seconds(first request is still loading!!!). CPU usage is at 99% all the time.

We have problems both in development and production servers.

In log I can find something nonsense like list of all queries and time consumed for them and when I sum it, result is about 9000ms, and the nonsense part is the last line in log which state:

Completed 200 OK in 43899ms (Views: 2288.7ms)

Any idea where to start digging?

Comment: Can you post code about how you query for the users? Are you embedding the notifications document in the user document?

Comment: It is not simple to post code, because there is a lot of templating and rendering partial views. Yes we are embedding notifications in user document. (default user scope is without notifications!)
One thing more, our default page on user profile is activity page. Activity items are stored in separate collection, and also problematic users have a lot of activity items.

Comment: Ok, can you post the RABL? If you aren't careful RABLs can really slow things down.

Comment: I tried now to write you our RABL structure, but it is way to complicated to post it here on stack.

Lets say that the problem is in rabl, how can you then explain behavior that first load last for more than 1 minute and if you try to open that page again in that 1 minute, you get whole response in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: To open that page in other tab*

Comment: Are you caching the RABL?

Comment: No.

We managed to solve problem. After removing all notifications from user collection, everything work as it is expected. Probably RABL ignored default scopes or something like that. We will move notifications to new collection and that will be solution.